# How to add a field that references an entity?

Tags: typeorm

Between the User and Coordination entities there is the following relationship, a user belongs to a coordination and a coordination can be shared by several users

User

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

Coordination

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Unique } from 'typeorm/browser';

@Entity()
// @Unique(['name', 'acronym'])
export class Coordination {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: false })
  acronym: string;
}
```

In this way, n coordinations can be created and eventually creating / editing a user could be associated with a single coordination

The solution that I have thought is to create a field in user that corresponds to a coordination. Expecting a foreign key to be created in the users table

Is this the correct way to do it?. Could you tell me how to implement this